# Why does Python's .write cause single quotes around the lines of text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, text-files

For whatever reason, the below code writes each 'line' of text into my .txt file with single quotations around each line. Is there a way to make that not happen? Or am I doing something to cause the problem?

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%r\n%r\n%r\n" % (line1, line2, line3))

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Comment: It's not `write` doing it. Try it in the prompt `>>> "%r\n%r\n%r\n" % ("your", "text", "here")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `%r` in your format string, which prints the `repr()` of your lines. What you want is `%s`:

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Additionally, I would recommend using a `with` statement to ensure the `target` file is closed, instead of calling `close()` manually. This will ensure that the file is closed even if your code causes an exception:

```
with open(filename) as target:
    ... do your manipulation ...
    # target is automatically closed at the end of the with block.
    # No need to call target.close() manually.
```

Comment: Oh, dang it! How did I not catch that? Thank you, it works now!

Comment: Updated my answer with a general observation, please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: That's actually very helpful. The exercise I was doing didn't include any of that, so that's a little better than before.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `%s` instead of `%r`. The latter option is for `repr()` (i.e., so you can produce a Python string object using the output).